# Ionic .pop() vs .dismiss()

Tags: ionic-framework

I watched a ionic online course. For getting rid of modal , it taught me to use .dismiss() of viewcontroller rather than .pop() of navcontroller. Why?  What is the difference of  these two?

Answer (score 1):

**NavController | push and pop** 
*Base controller class for Ionic*

You can push a new page onto the top of the navigation stack with .push().
Whilst the other way around, you can pop of a page of that stack with .pop().

**ModalController and ViewController | present and dismiss**

A Modal is a content pane that goes over the user's current page. 
The modal is presented over the users page and can be closed using the ViewController's dismiss method. This dismiss method can return data that is passed in.

*See docs below*
[NavController](https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/navigation/NavController/)
[ModalController](https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/components/modal/ModalController/)
[ViewController](https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/navigation/ViewController/)